# Choose right connection string(Error While making connection with Excel File)

Tags: c#, excel

I m trying to make connection with Excel.
I have used many of connection string But no one is working.

**Connection String 1 Gives error-**The 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.

Filepath="C:\"

1-var ConStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + Filepath + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0"

This Connection string Gives error string "Unspecified error"

2-var ConStr= "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="+Filepath+";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;\"";

```
        using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(ConStr))
            {
            conn.Open();
}
```

How to Choose right Connection string?

MY System Configuration:

Window Server 2008 R2 Sp1
Microsoft office 64 Bit.
Visual Studio 2010 Professional

Comment: Please consider improving the [formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) of your question to make it easier to read and understand.

Answer (score 1):

> The Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Jet and the Jet ODBC driver are
>   available in 32-bit versions only. You can't run them in 64 bit mode.

From [this page](http://www.connectionstrings.com/using-jet-in-64-bit-environments/) at connectionstrings.com.

The page confirms you can either adapt to run in 32bit mode or download the 64 bit driver.

Comment: I have already Install  "Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable" from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255
still It is not Working.??